# Yum identifies but does not install dependency

Tags: rpm, yum, rpmbuild

I have my own rpm repository for yum but I'm having a problem with one package - yum indicates that it sees the dependencies, but it decides **not** to install one of them, without showing any error messages. The problem is neatly captured in the yum output ("stomppy" is the problem dependency)

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package lrms-skippy.noarch 0:1a.5.0-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: elementtree for package: lrms-skippy-1a.5.0-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: stomppy for package: lrms-skippy-1a.5.0-1.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package elementtree.noarch 0:1.2.6-1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

As you can see, yum knows that "lrms-skippy" depends on both stomppy and elementtree, but wants to install **only** elementree. These are all spec files I wrote myself. The dependencies of "lrms-skippy" are declared as follows:

```
Requires: python, lrms-stomppy, lrms-elementtree
```

Just in case the stomppy package is already installed, I tried removing it:

```
[root@centos_6 ~]# yum remove lrms-stomppy
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: lrms-stomppy
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos-mirror.jchost.net
 * extras: yum.phx.singlehop.com
 * updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
Package(s) lrms-stomppy available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

As you can see, the package is available but not installed.

So why would yum behave this way - simply decide not to install the dependency without any errors or explanation? Yum version 3.2.29. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. The elementree package was claiming to provide stomppy, so there was no need for yum to install stomppy.  I don't know why my elementree rpm was making this false claim since this is not in my spec file but rebuilding the elementree package has fixed the issue. All internal rpms and spec files so I will have to put my hand up to this one.